# Where is the gae local datastore on a mac OSX 10.8.3 filesystem?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have tried all the suggestions from these posts:

[Does anyone know where the Google App Engine local datastore file located for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753914/does-anyone-know-where-the-google-app-engine-local-datastore-file-located-for-ma)

[Where is my local App Engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588817/where-is-my-local-app-engine-datastore)

[Google App Engine local datastore path configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697990/google-app-engine-local-datastore-path-configuration)

and I still can not find my local datastore.

I don't have the SDK set to clear the datastore on startup plus I can't find it even when the appserver is running. Does anyone know the file path for the Google App Engine's development server datastore file?

I am running GAE SDK 1.7.7.

Comment: I'm running OSX - developing in Java.  It's just a local_db.bin file in WEB-INF/appengine-generated on my machine.  You didn't tag as Java or Python, so I'm answering from a Java perspective.  Can you just go into Finder and look for it ?

Comment: thanks planetjones. I can't find WEB-INF or appengine-generated. I did try using Finder and no luck. Maybe Java sdk has a different file system. Thank you though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Got this answer from a friend of mine. Worked for me and I hope it helps somebody else out.

By default, it's [local datastore] stored in a pretty much random directory. My current one looks like /private/var/folders/81/ABUNCHOFCRAP/T/..../datastore.db. Luckily, it's always called datastore.db. If yours is structured the same way mine is, you can find it using the following command in your Terminal:

```
find /private/var/folders -name datastore.db
```

That should print out the full path of the file you're looking for, along with a bunch of "Permission denied" messages. If that doesn't yield anything, use this command:

```
find / -name datastore.db
```

That one might take a while to run (it looks in all of the directories you have access to), but it'll definitely find it if it's there. Just copy one of those commands into your Terminal, and you should be all set. Let me know if this helps.